# How get all headers including post data in web Client class?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, request-headers

I'm looking for an code example how get all received headers in my web application including the post data.

something as:

```
String headers = client.Headers.ToString(); 
Response.Write(headers);
```

Output:

```
       POST http://localhost:52133/test/Default.aspx HTTP/1.1
        Host: localhost:52133
        User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1
        Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
        Connection: keep-alive
        foo: baa
        Pragma: no-cache


      *the post data*
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Request.Headers will not include the posted data. The posted data can be accessed via Request.Form object like the following:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < Request.Form.Count; i++)
 {
     string key = Request.Form.GetKey(i);
     string value = Request.Form[i];
     // now do something with the key-value pair...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the [`Request.ServerVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property.  You can loop through it like this:

```
Dim loop1, loop2 As Integer
Dim arr1(), arr2() As String
Dim coll As NameValueCollection

' Load ServerVariable collection into NameValueCollection object.
coll=Request.ServerVariables 
' Get names of all keys into a string array.
arr1 = coll.AllKeys 
For loop1 = 0 To arr1.GetUpperBound(0)
   Response.Write("Key: " & arr1(loop1) & "<br>")
   arr2 = coll.GetValues(loop1) ' Get all values under this key.
   For loop2 = 0 To arr2.GetUpperBound(0)
      Response.Write("Value " & CStr(loop2) & ": " & Server.HtmlEncode(arr2(loop2)) & "<br>")
   Next loop2
Next loop1
```

The ones that start with "HEADER_" are the raw HTTP headers. See MSDN's [IIS Server variables documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx) for more info.